# c# My getter isn't working

Tags: c#

I'm trying to program an anagram analyzer in Visual Studio for my class, but my list is empty when I call the getter from another class.

```
public class UserInput
{
    private String fileName;
    private string text;
    private string[] words;
    private List<string> preparedWord = new List<string>();
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\s-|[^A-Za-z0-9])");
    private string t = "testing";

    public void promptFile()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a .txt file");
        this.fileName = Console.ReadLine();
        this.fileConversion();
        this.wordSeperator();

       // foreach (string word in this.preparedWord)
        //{
          //  System.Console.WriteLine(word);
        //}

        //{
        //    System.Console.WriteLine(this.preparedWord.Count);
        //}
    }

    public String getFileName
    {
        get { return this.t; }
    }

    private void fileConversion()
    {
         StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(this.fileName);
        this.text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    public void wordSeperator()
    {
        this.words = text.Split(' ', ',', '.', ':','\t');

        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            this.preparedWord.Add(reg.Replace(s, ""));// @"\W\S", ""));
        }
    }

    public List<string> getPreparedList{
         get
         {
              return this.preparedWord;}
         } 
}
}
```

Here is where I removed the unwanted characters and made a list of the characters that are valid. I made a string to test to see if it will show and it did, but the preparedWord list doesn't show correctly.

```
 class AnagramManager
 {
     FileToStringConverter fileString = new FileToStringConverter();

     UserInput u = new UserInput();
     // string pattern = @"[\d-]";
     //Regex reg;
     String test = "123rrtdfr34 h%$5 yy.yy hjh-hk 788995a";

     public static string RemoveDigits(string key)
     {
         return Regex.Replace(key, @"\d", "");  
     }

     public void writeList()
     {
        foreach (string word in this.u.getPreparedList)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(word);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine(this.u.getFileName);
     }
}
```

When I call the method for it to write the words it's blank and it says that the count is 0. Everything is as it should be when I write the list in the UserInput class.

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: @Smac89 - No he's got it right

Comment: Are you sure `wordSeperator()` is being called? It's only called by `promptFile()`, which isn't called by anything.

Comment: @musical_coder I'm sorry I forgot to paste the class with the main method where I called promptFile(). But yes it is called.

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that, otherwise you wouldn't be having a problem. This is actually a great opportunity to use the debugger. Set a breakpoint at `promptFile()` where it's being called in your `main()`, walk through your program, and make sure that it's passing through `wordSeperator()` (and actually inserting words!).

Comment: It says that the count is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate your UserInput class from your AnagramManager class, you never assign anything to it.  You use:

```
UserInput u = new UserInput();
```

And then you have an empty instance of your class.  You'll need to define a constructor to put some data in it, or populate it from AnagramManager.

Comment: I don't understand. Sorry, I'm new to c#